# How can I get the lead out for creating a Snow Leopard Server virtual machine under VMware?

Tags: vmware, macos

I have a DVD for Snow Leopard Server, and I have an MBP running Monterey and under it VMware Fusion 13.0.2.

I am trying to make a virtual machine, allocated 4G RAM for the guest OS, and disabled side channel mitigations.

I'm trying to boot the VM to install Snow Leopard Server, and it gets quickly to the screen below and my CD drive is chirping... and has been for a couple of days. I am not getting to the point of being asked for details for setting up the system and creating an account:

[image]

What should I be doing to make a Snow Leopard Server VM?

Comment: What Mac is it? I'm not sure Fusion can run Intel OSes on M1/2 yet.

Comment: @Tetsujin It can't.  Neither can Parallels.

Comment: Please confirm that you are using an Intel MBP.

Comment: Also that you are using a retail SLS CD, not one that came with an XServe or Mini Server. See https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/2005793

Comment: I’m running a slightly older MBP (I5 chipset).  I’m also using a retail CD. @Gilby, thanks for checking in with me on both.

Comment: I can't answer for Fusion, as I run Parallels, but I do vaguely recall after Parallels hard-killed regular Snow Leo from being used [even if you'd been using it for years meaning you lost all your work!!] that I had to find some 'specially tweaked' SL Server installer to get past an issue with installing direct from the CD. I already had the CD & license, but ended up using a 'dodgy download' [albeit from a reliable source] to persuade it to install. Unfortunately I don't know what the tweak was or where I got the installer now:\

Comment: I have a SL (not SLS) vm I made 11 years ago with Fusion 4 (it still boots fine). When building I don't remember getting stuck where you are. All the tricks were in getting Fusion to accept the non-server SL client (some say that breaks the Apple license). Is your CD Apple Part Number: MC588Z/A as used in https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/installing-snow-leopard-and-rosetta-into-parallels-7-in-lion.1365439/page-23?post=17285039#post-17285039

Comment: @Gilby Yes; it is that part number.